# Putting arrays into another array

Tags: c++, arrays

How do I store a list of arrays into another set of array? I tried this way but it doesn't work.

```
float data1[5] = {150.0, 203.0, 165.0, 4.0, 36.0};
float data2[5] = {249.0, 255.0, 253.0, 104.0, 2.0};

float allData[2] = {data1, data2};

cout << allData[1][2] << endl;     //this should print 253.0 but it has error
```

This didn't allow me to compile. I also tried to change it to `float *allData[2] = {data1, data2};` and it allowed me to compile but I don't get the result I want.

What have I done wrong in this?
Thanks.

Comment: use std::vector if developping in C++, much less pain in general :)

Comment: Using your second form, `float *allData[2] = {data1, data2}` actually gives you the correct answer: http://ideone.com/kE70q

Comment: @Sevilla: It says that "expression needs to have a pointer-to-object type".

Comment: @xEnOn: `float *allData[2]` is not the same as `float allData[2]`.

Comment: @Charles: The one with the `*` is a pointer while the one without the asterisk has the exact value, right? I tried `float *allData[2]` but got that error that says "expression needs to have a pointer-to-object type".

Comment: @xEnOn: I thought you said that that version "allowed you to compile"?

Comment: It allows me to compile. If I change to `float *allData[2]`, I could compile. But I cannot compile when trying to use `allData[1][2]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use vectors (this example is in C++11):

```
std::vector<float> data1 = {150.0, 203.0, 165.0, 4.0, 36.0};
std::vector<float> data2 = {249.0, 255.0, 253.0, 104.0, 2.0};

std::vector<std::vector<float>> allData = {data1, data2};
std::cout << allData[0][0] << std::endl;
```

Note: possibly you want to store pointers to vectors in allData to prevent copying the data, but you should always take care with such constructs as this could very quickly lead to dangling pointers. This is also the case for the solution with plain arrays by the way.

Edit, as R. Martinho Fernandes mentioned in comments:

You can change the construct of `allData` to:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> allData = {std::move(data1), std::move(data2)};
```

It's worth to note however that after this operation `data1` and `data2` will be emtpy as their contents are moved to `allData`. If you do not need them anymore this is the version to prefer (no pointers, no copying).

Comment: Use moves instead of pointers! `std::vector<std::vector<float>> allData = { std::move(data1), std::move(data2) };` is extremely cheap.

Comment: @Fernandes: The `move()` will copy the whole data instead of keeping the pointer?

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: how stupid of me to forget about one of C++11's most important new features, thank you for reminding. Edited the answer.

Comment: @xEnOn: no, the move will probably just swap some vector internal pointers. This means you cannot expect `data1` and `data2` to still have the original data.

Comment: If `data1` and `data2` are not the original data, what would they become?

Comment: @xEnOn: as stated in my answer: empty. I'm not 100% sure if this is standard defined, but I can't imagine any implementation doing it otherwise.

Comment: By the way, can I even initialise it this way: `std::vector<float> data1 = {150.0, 203.0, 165.0, 4.0, 36.0};`?
I get an error that says "initialization with '{...}' not allowed for object of type" when I do this. I using push_back as a workaround to this but this shorthand will be really convenient if it works.

Comment: That is C++11 generalized initializer syntax, if you use gcc you can compile with `-std=c++0x`

Comment: hmm..I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I added that `-std=c++0x` to the command line options but it still doesn't let me use this syntax. Maybe Visual Studio just don't let me use this shorthand.

Comment: @xEnOn: yeah, Visual Studio doesn't support that initialization syntax yet. It does support the move semantics, though. Regarding what `data1` and `data2` would become, it is unspecified. They are however, guaranteed to still be valid objects, so you can do things like assign them something else, for example.

Answer (score 4):

You can't store arrays that already exist into another array because array objects can't be moved. You can either form an array or arrays:

```
float allData[][5] = 
{
    {150.0, 203.0, 165.0, 4.0, 36.0},
    {249.0, 255.0, 253.0, 104.0, 2.0}
};
```

Or you can make your second array an array of pointers to the previous array.

```
float *allData[] = { data1, data2 };
```

or even:

```
float (*allData[])[5] = { &data1, &data2 };
```

For all of the above, the expression `allData[1][2]` should yield the `float` value 253 (the third element of the second array).

Comment: well, you can memcpy over the existing values from one array to another, but the array cannot overflow. So in that case, you can store one array into another but you lose the existing values.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: I'm afraid I can't understand what you mean in you comment, can you clarify?

Comment: You can use memcpy(dst,src,n) to copy one array into another. That "erases" whatever was in dst, but I was countering your statement that "You can't store arrays that already exist into another array", because you can albeit with data loss.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: That's just copying values from one array to another. What you can't do is put a named array `data1` into a named array `allData` and expect fiddling with `data1` to affect `allData` of _vice versa_.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `float[2][]` for a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

```
float data1[5] = {150.0, 203.0, 165.0, 4.0, 36.0};
float data2[5] = {249.0, 255.0, 253.0, 104.0, 2.0};

float** allData = new float*[2]; 

allData[0] = &data1[0]; 
allData[1] = &data2[0];

cout << allData[1][2] << endl;     //prints 253.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `float *allData [2]` is the correct way to do what you are looking for. Trying the code out using DevStudio 2010 works for me. What output are you getting and what were you expecting.

I get `253` as the output, were you expecting `253.0`? In which case, you need to specify the output format for floats:

```
cout.precision (1); 
cout.setf (ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
cout << allData[1][2] << endl;     // this prints 253.0
```